# Who is the blue elf lady in the Bad Anon meeting?

Tags: character, wreck-it-ralph

In *Wreck it Ralph*, the video game bad guys are having their Bad Anon meeting. I've been able to identify all the bad guys in the meeting, except for the blue elf lady in the red dress. In the picture below she's in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Who is she?

Comment: From [The Familiar Faces of Wreck-It Ralph](http://www.ign.com/articles/2012/06/09/the-familiar-faces-of-wreck-it-ralph), "Disney confirmed that the tentacled, crown-wearing monster is just a generic creature not tied to any particular game."  So, it's possible that the blue elf lady is also an original character for the movie.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Really? I always thought it was a beholder from the Dungeons & Dragons games.

Comment: A [Beholder](https://www.google.com/search?q=beholder&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Y83&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mcqXUL_WHpCK9gTEnoH4Cg&ved=0CFQQsAQ&biw=1248&bih=876) is one-eyed and all tentacle-y, but the green guy is the wrong color, and I think he's too big.

Comment: I was thinking the green tentacled thing was a Malbro from the Final Fantasy games...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may be [Mishaela](http://shining.wikia.com/wiki/Mishaela), a minor villain from *Shining Force*. Same pointy ears and blue skin and belt, though her hair is usually shown as purple and her dress a bit less sexy!

[image][image]

Comment: According to [this Wikia](http://wreckitralph.wikia.com/wiki/Sorceress), she isn't. No references though …

Answer (score 5):

The dress reminds me of a skin for a champion of League of Legends named [**Evelynn**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Evelynn/Background) (Slightly NSFW as the character's base skin has very skimpy garments)

[image]

Though she is not a villain in the game itself, she is known as **The Widowmaker** and when picked in the game, generally causes a lot of panic to the opponents, as she has a deadly stealth mechanic and is typically known for nuking enemies, when played properly.

Comment: I don't think its Evelynn. The outfit isn't right for it to be Evelynn. Evelynn is much sluttier than the girl blue elf girl in Wreck-It Ralph.

Comment: @Jade That doesn't mean they couldn't have cleaned her up a little for the movie.  Alas, the answer is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think she is a Minor Boss-thing Lady from Zelda....one of the old versions. Her minions tried to kidnap Zelda from Link..

Comment: Veran, is who you are thinking of.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought he tentacle green monster was from Mario or Kirby,Prabally wrong. But the elf
girl,perhaps a majorly changed look from Vaati from a legend of zelda game.But I'm just guessing.(is that guy nex to Bowser and eggman from Street fighter?)

Answer (score -2):

The beholder in dungeons and dragons is able to change its size and yes it has tentacles but there are eyeballs at the tip of each tentacle and it does have one eye.   Only thing wrong with it is that it is green—the original color is a purple gray color.  I know this because I am a fantasy nut.  So yes, it very well could be a beholder or maybe Disney used the idea and made it their own.  As for the blue elf, I think she's from Zelda. I'm a full time gamer so ask me anything

Comment: I think this probably should have been added as a comment to the question, rather than posting as an answer. It addresses an additional query that arose in the comment discussion, but doesn't address the original question.

Answer (score -2):

Also known as Michaela, Mishela is a powerful wizard and a prophet from Sega's Shining Force series of RPGs.

Comment: This answer is adding no value to existing answers. Even the same answer is presented by MaryJoFinch and even got selected.

Answer (score -3):

She is probably Morag from dragon quest 9. She is the boss who loved the knight

Comment: The look an coloring are similar, but Morag doesn't have feet and she has wings, neither of which are present here.